# Need a PHP email send script for HTML an form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a single page portfolio website that I'm building and I have a contact form that I need to process using php send script. I'm a novice when it comes to PHP so I'm having trouble getting this to work. I've done some searching but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Here's what I have done, I copied this from a PHP contact page that I had built but the PHP and form are on the same page and I need an external send.php to process my form.

```
<?php
             $error    = ''; // error message
             $name     = ''; // sender's name
             $email    = ''; // sender's email address
             $company  = ''; // company name
             $subject  = ''; // subject
             $comment  = ''; // the message itself

        if(isset($_POST['send']))
        {
             $name     = $_POST['name'];
             $email    = $_POST['email'];
             $company  = $_POST['company'];
             $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
             $comment  = $_POST['comment'];

            if($error == '')
            {
                if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                    $message = stripslashes($message);
                }

                // the email will be sent here
                // make sure to change this to be your e-mail
                $to      = "example@email.com";

                // the email subject
                // '[Contact Form] :' will appear automatically in the subject.
                // You can change it as you want

                $subject = '[Contact Form] : ' . $subject;

                // the mail message ( add any additional information if you want )
                $msg     = "From : $name \r\ne-Mail : $email \r\nCompany : $company \r\nSubject : $subject \r\n\n" . "Message : \r\n$message";

                mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
            }
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['send']) || $error != '')
        {

              header("location: http://www.#.com/#contact");

        }
        ?>
```

So for my form I want to have:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" class="form">
```

I plan on using HTML5 and jQuery to validate the form, so I really only need the script to capture the info and send the email to a single address. After it sends I want the script to redirect back to the Contact page.

Edit:

I found a solution after spending a while on google.
    http://www.website.com/#contact");
    ?>

Comment: You obviously have not looked at the hundreds of other questions relating to this before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you haven't initialized the value for `$message`

```
$message = stripslashes($message);
```

You probably meant to use `$comment` instead of `$message`

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that, I copied the code from a previous form.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what problem you're facing. Simply copy the PHP you have into a file called send.php and my first glance says it'll work if you change $message back to $comment and add error checking. If you still have issues, post back with more details.